# R Predict produces values different than manual computation

Tags: r, excel, regression

I'm trying to manually compute a prediction of a value given Coefficients products in R for a multivariate polynomial model however my predicted value in Excel is wildly incorrect whereas the predict() produces the correct value.

Below is my manual computation in Excel, the `predicted time` cell is `=SUMPRODUCT(CoefficientMatrix,MM of Predictors)` [image: Manual prediction in Excel]

Below is the code in R, the `predict()` gives me the value of 126 which is the correct value. Why is my excel computation so far off?
[image: R code]

Comment: I can't tell but sometimes, in Excel, an issue can be that the coefficients are not entered with sufficient precision.

Comment: Sorry totally unrelated comment. what syntax highlighting theme you're using in R?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld anyway to increase precision?

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I'm using IntelliJ with the R plugin and the Material Theme plugin

Comment: How are you entering the coefficients into Excel?  Are you using a rounded value?

Comment: I'm just copying and pasting them from R console

Comment: Can you examine the full underlying values to ensure they are identical?  (In `Excel` you would examine the **formula bar**, not sure about `R`). If so, then precision is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As based on the comments and a bit of googling it is true that Excel is rounding some of the values which are very important in their level of precision.

Using the `coeff()` function in R produces the coeffecients to the correct precision then ensuring these values aren't rounded in Excel will produce results exact to those using the `predict()` function